# Get quarter start/end dates for more than a year (start year to current year)

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-range

I've been trying to get start and end dates range for each quarter given a specific date/year, like this:

```
 SELECT DATEADD(mm, (quarter - 1) * 3, year_date) StartDate,
       DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEADD(mm, quarter * 3, year_date)) EndDate
       --quarter QuarterNo
  FROM
(
  SELECT '2012-01-01' year_date
) s CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT 1 quarter UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4
) q
```

which produces the following output:

```
2012-01-01 00:00:00 2012-04-01 00:00:00
2012-04-01 00:00:00 2012-07-01 00:00:00
2012-07-01 00:00:00 2012-10-01 00:00:00
2012-10-01 00:00:00 2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Problem: I need to do this for a given **start_date** and **end_date**, the problem being the end_date=current_day, so how can I achieve this:

```
2012-01-01 00:00:00 2012-04-01 00:00:00
2012-04-01 00:00:00 2012-07-01 00:00:00
2012-07-01 00:00:00 2012-10-01 00:00:00
2012-10-01 00:00:00 2013-01-01 00:00:00
    ...   ...
2021-01-01 00:00:00   2021-01-06 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what you want to do :

```
SET startdatevar AS DATEtime = '2020-01-10' 
;WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (

SELECT startdatevar AS startdate , DATEADD(QUARTER, 1  , startdatevar) enddate , 1 quarter
UNION ALL 
SELECT enddate , CASE WHEN DATEADD(QUARTER, 1  , enddate) > CURRENT_DATE() THEN GETDATE() ELSE DATEADD(QUARTER, 1  , enddate) END enddate, quarter + 1
FROM cte 
WHERE 
    cte.enddate <= CURRENT_DATE()
     and quarter < 4
)


SELECT * FROM cte
```

to use your code , if you want to have more than 4 quarters :

```
SET quarter_limit = DATEDIFF(quarter , <startdate>,<enddate>)
;WITH RECURSIVE cte(q, qDate,enddate) as
    (
        select 1,    
          DATEFROMPARTS(year('2012-01-01'::date), 1, 1) -- First quarter date
         ,time_slice('2012-01-01'::date, 3, 'MONTH', 'END')
         UNION ALL
         select q+1,
         DATEADD(q, 1, qdate) -- next quarter start date
         ,time_slice(qdate::date, (q+1)*3, 'MONTH', 'END')
         from cte
         where q < quarter_limit -- limiting the number of next quarters
         AND cte.endDate <= <enddate>
     )
     SELECT * FROM cte
```

Comment: since i don't have access to snowflake db righthnow, it might not be 100% the right syntax , but it should be working , what's the error message you are getting ( if any)?

Answer (score 0):

After [@eshirvana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367454/eshirvana)'s answer, I came up with this slightly change after your answer:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(q, qDate,enddate) as
    (
        select 1,    
          DATEFROMPARTS(year('2012-01-01'::date), 1, 1) -- First quarter date
         ,time_slice('2012-01-01'::date, 3, 'MONTH', 'END')
         UNION ALL
         select q+1,
         DATEADD(q, 1, qdate) -- next quarter start date
         ,time_slice(qdate::date, (q+1)*3, 'MONTH', 'END')
         from cte
         where q <4 -- limiting the number of next quarters
         AND cte.endDate <= CURRENT_DATE() 
     )
     SELECT * FROM cte
```

Which works fine for whatever year I pass there (2012 will produce 4 records, 2021 just one, since we're still on the first quarter right now).

[EDIT]: it still doesn't work as expected after your 2nd code sugestion:

```
 WITH RECURSIVE cte(q, qDate,enddate) as
    (
        select 1,    
          DATEFROMPARTS(year('2012-01-01'::date), 1, 1) -- First quarter date
         ,CASE  WHEN time_slice('2012-01-01'::date, 3, 'MONTH', 'END') > CURRENT_DATE
            THEN current_date 
            ELSE time_slice('2012-01-01'::date, 3, 'MONTH', 'END') 
            END
         UNION ALL
         select q+1,
         DATEADD(q, 1, qdate) -- next quarter start date
         ,time_slice(qdate::date, (q+1)*3, 'MONTH', 'END')
         from cte
         where q < DATEDIFF(quarter , '2012-01-01'::date,'2021-01-06'::date)
         AND cte.endDate <= '2021-01-06'::date
     )
     SELECT * FROM cte
```

is outputing this:
Sorry [@eshirvana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367454/eshirvana), it doesn't work as expected though. It all goes well to some point, but it's not returning all the records. Instead, it produces less records and wrong one, like this:

```
1   2012-01-01  2012-04-01
2   2012-04-01  2012-07-01
3   2012-07-01  2012-10-01
4   2012-10-01  2013-01-01
5   2013-01-01  2013-10-01
6   2013-04-01  2013-07-01
7   2013-07-01  2013-10-01
8   2013-10-01  2014-01-01
9   2014-01-01  2015-01-01
10  2014-04-01  2015-01-01
11  2014-07-01  2016-10-01
12  2014-10-01  2015-01-01
13  2015-01-01  2015-07-01
14  2015-04-01  2015-07-01
15  2015-07-01  2018-10-01
16  2015-10-01  2018-01-01
17  2016-01-01  2016-10-01
18  2016-04-01  2019-07-01
19  2016-07-01  2017-07-01
20  2016-10-01  2020-01-01
21  2017-01-01  2017-04-01
22  2017-04-01  2019-07-01
23  2017-07-01  2021-10-01
```

Although my logic it's still not ok for not printing just Q1 dates for 2021, could this output issues be related to date format or something?

Comment: just replace CURRENT_DATE()  with the date you want as enddate

Comment: It doesn't work. If I choose other day for that, it will print all the 4 start_dt/end_dt *just* for 2012. I would like to iterate over some years, which would mean to apply this for 2012-01-01, 2013-01-01, ... and so on.
The main idea it's there, yes, but it only works for a year.

Comment: oh I see , so you need to calculate the level (q) by finding how many quarter there is between your start date and end date, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Now, it seems to be working, at least for 2012-01-01 till today (2021-01-06).

The code :

```
 WITH RECURSIVE cte(q, qDate,enddate) as
    (
        select 
        -- it might not be the first quarter, so better to protect that:
         quarter('2012-01-01'::date)::numeric 
        , DATEFROMPARTS(year('2012-01-01'::date), 1, 1) -- First quarter date
        , CASE WHEN time_slice('2012-01-01'::date, 3, 'MONTH', 'END') > '2021-01-06'::date
            THEN '2021-01-06'::date
            ELSE time_slice('2012-01-01'::date, 3, 'MONTH', 'END') 
            END
         UNION ALL
         select q+1
         , DATEADD(q, 1, qdate) -- next quarter start date
         ,CASE  WHEN time_slice(DATEADD(q, 1, qdate), 3, 'MONTH', 'END')> '2021-01-06'::date
            THEN '2021-01-06'::date
            ELSE time_slice(DATEADD(q, 1, qdate), 3, 'MONTH', 'END')
            END
         from cte
         where q <= DATEDIFF(quarter , '2012-01-01'::date,'2021-01-06'::date)
         AND cte.endDate <= '2021-01-06'::date
     )
     SELECT * FROM cte
```

The output:

```
1   2012-01-01  2012-04-01
2   2012-04-01  2012-07-01
3   2012-07-01  2012-10-01
4   2012-10-01  2013-01-01
5   2013-01-01  2013-04-01
6   2013-04-01  2013-07-01
7   2013-07-01  2013-10-01
8   2013-10-01  2014-01-01
9   2014-01-01  2014-04-01
10  2014-04-01  2014-07-01
11  2014-07-01  2014-10-01
12  2014-10-01  2015-01-01
13  2015-01-01  2015-04-01
14  2015-04-01  2015-07-01
15  2015-07-01  2015-10-01
16  2015-10-01  2016-01-01
17  2016-01-01  2016-04-01
18  2016-04-01  2016-07-01
19  2016-07-01  2016-10-01
20  2016-10-01  2017-01-01
21  2017-01-01  2017-04-01
22  2017-04-01  2017-07-01
23  2017-07-01  2017-10-01
24  2017-10-01  2018-01-01
25  2018-01-01  2018-04-01
26  2018-04-01  2018-07-01
27  2018-07-01  2018-10-01
28  2018-10-01  2019-01-01
29  2019-01-01  2019-04-01
30  2019-04-01  2019-07-01
31  2019-07-01  2019-10-01
32  2019-10-01  2020-01-01
33  2020-01-01  2020-04-01
34  2020-04-01  2020-07-01
35  2020-07-01  2020-10-01
36  2020-10-01  2021-01-01
37  2021-01-01  2021-01-06
```

In case you're wondering: yes, the idea is to present the end_date as last_day of the month+one. But it could easily be adapted.

It's not pretty, but I think it's somehow easy to understand.